# What kind of C++ code would generate this x86 assembly instruction?

Tags: c++, assembly, x86, reverse-engineering

I have been "reverse engineering" some of my own libraries to learn more about compiler optimizations. I have seen one of my simplest class constructors (a 4-D vector) get compiled to the following:

```
fldz                                                        ; push +0.0 to FPU stack
mov     eax, ecx                                            ; set eax to this (ecx)
mov     dword ptr [eax], offset data_??_7vector_t@data@@6B@ ; what is this doing?
fst     dword ptr [eax+4]                                   ; assign this->first
fst     dword ptr [eax+8]                                   ; assign this->second
fst     dword ptr [eax+0Ch]                                 ; assign this->third
fstp    dword ptr [eax+10h]                                 ; assign this->fourth, pop FPU stack
retn                                                        ; return this (eax)
```

On the third line, I have no clue what this is doing. I originally thought it might be some kind of optimization that is referencing some hard coded block of constant data.

In order to determine what it might be, I loaded the DLL into a container process and then attached a debugger and viewed the data at the location of `data??_7vector_t@data@@6B@`, but it was just `db offset unk??_7vector_t@data2@@6B@`. I followed that second label and there was a region of data which didn't correspond to anything I recognized in my project, even after converting the first 8 bytes into a double.

The compiler I'm using is MSVC++ with Visual Studio 2013 with full optimization without any advanced instruction sets (SSE, etc is turned off).

What C++ code would generate the instruction in question?

Comment: Better ask this at [reverseengineering.se], it deals with just these kinds of questions.

Comment: `data??_7vector_t@data@@6B@` I think it is a mangled name.

Comment: @sashoalm Didn't realize there was an SE site for that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure where the `data_` prefix comes from, but the `?` is the standard marker of decorated (mangled) names and you can use the `undname` tool to decipher them:

```
>undname ??_7vector_t@data@@6B@
Microsoft (R) C++ Name Undecorator
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Undecoration of :- "??_7vector_t@data@@6B@"
is :- "const data::vector_t::`vftable'"
```

So yes, it's just initializing the vtable pointer.

Comment: Ahh I didn't know Microsoft had a tool for that. I've been using the one in another program that only unmangles exported function names. Thanks for that extra bit there!

Answer (score 1):

The line in question is assigning a vtable pointer to the object being constructed.

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like it is applying a constructor to the uninitialized storage at ECX.

The steps of that would insert a vtable pointer in its first slot, and zero the 4d vector you say your application uses.